# How to access PostgreSQL (CentOS 9) from PGAdmin4 (Windows 10)

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, centos, pgadmin-4

I've set up **Hyper-V** on my laptop and created **two Virtual Machines**: one running **CentOS 9** and the other running **Windows 10**.

On the **CentOS 9 VM**, I've installed **PostgreSQL**, while on the **Windows 10 VM**, I've installed **PGAdmin4**. Essentially, each operating system is running on its own VM.

I'm currently trying to **establish a connection** from **PostgreSQL (CentOS 9)** to **PGAdmin4 (Windows 10)** but haven't been successful so far.

I've researched extensively but haven't found a solution. Could someone please provide guidance on this or share relevant information?

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem, not a question about software development.